# Is it permissible to name one's child with a name from the opposite gender?

Tags: halacha, minhag, names, tanach, children-parenting

Is a person allowed to name a boy with a girl's name and vice versa?

I remember seeing that one musn't, although in Nach one finds these things a lot.
I understand it is not best practice for shidduchim, but I would still like to know the sources on this.

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5734.

Comment: FWIW, I know a female _N'sanya_ (although of course in _Tanach_ it's a man's name).

Comment: I think rabbi Kanievsky is against it, in most situations but with names he is a dass Yachid in  what he says like his opposition to the Name Shira

Comment: One of the more common male (nick)names in Israel, "Avi", is actually only used in Tanach in reference to somebody's mother.

Comment: @simchashatorah, Yeah, do you know what R' Kanievsky has agaisnt the name Shira?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17323

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17297/1059

Comment: Followup to some of these comments: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26455

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In "What's in a Name", the English translation of Zusha Wilhelm's sefer "Ziv HaShemot", the [following is stated](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/273286/jewish/5-Giving-a-Boy-a-Feminine-Name-and-Vice-Versa.htm) (Hebrew version with footnotes [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53094&pgnum=44)):

> 1) Some say that one may name a male child after a female. *(See Bris Avos 8:37; See also Koreis HaBris, Posach Eliyahu, note 8; See Kuntres HaShemos (revised edition), Vol 7, p. 10; See Sefer HaBris, p. 313; See the Midrash on Pinchas (13:12) )* Others maintain that it is better not to convert a feminine name to a masculine one. *(See Sefer HaMetzaref chapter 3; Responsa Tzitz Eliezer, Vol. 11, ch. 56, and references to Vol 7, 49:13)*
>
> 2) It is not proper to name a female after a male. *(See Bris Avos 8:37)* Some authorities disagree, and do have a custom of giving a man’s names to a female. *(See Responsa HaMaor, Vol 1, p. 134, and in Responsa Mevaser Tov, stating that this is the custom in America. See Noam, Vol. 8, p, 192; See Devash , p. 299)*

In the next chapter, the [following is stated](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/273287/jewish/6-Names-Common-to-Both-Males-and-Females.htm) (Hebrew version with footnotes [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53094&pgnum=48)):

> Some say that one should not give his child a name that is common to both males and females. *(See Responsa Divrei Malkiel 3:75; See also Responsa of R. Shmuel di Medina, Even HaEzer 65)*

`I got a hold of the printed book and added the sources to this answer. The book itself not only brings the sources, but quotes most of them.`

---

As @ba pointed out in the footnotes, the [Tzitz Eliezer 21:4:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14520&pgnum=23) brings opinions that permit it, as well as opinions that are against it.

Comment: The chasam sofer called his daughter simcha which is common to both @Menachem and perhaps more common to males called bunem or binyamin (because of ben oni) see names in SA.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. It discusses changing names, but although it discusses giving a man's name to women, or neutral names to either, it doesn't discuss giving a woman's name to men.

Answer (score 6):

The [Rivivos Efraim 1:109](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1081&st=&pgnum=85) mentions in the name of the [Tzitz Eliezer 7:49:13](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14506&st=&pgnum=260) that it is not proper to name a male after a female or vice versa.

Comment: The Tzitz Eliezer 21:4:4 quoted in my answer mentions this Tzitz Eliezer (7:49:13) and then says he later saw the Shu"T Divrei Malchiel who brings several reason why one should not do this.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer from Rabbi Shlomo Aviner:

> Naming a Daughter after a Male Relative
>
> Q: I saw that Ha-Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach said that there is
>   absolutely no reason to name a daughter after a male relative
>   (Ve-Alehu Lo Yibul Volume 2, p. 142).  And it is written in Shut Tzitz
>   Eliezer (7:49 #13) that a strict person will refrain from doing so. 
>   What is Ha-Rav's opinion?  Is it permissible to name a daughter after
>   a male relative if he had a name used for both males and females, such
>   as Simchah orYonah, or a name that can be feminized, such as
>   Nachum-Nechama, Yosef-Yosefa or Tzion-Tziona?
>
> A: It is a stricture not to do so, but according to the basic
>   Halachah, it is permissible.

Answer (score 3):

> It is preferable to name a baby boy after a man and a baby girl after
>   a woman and to use the original name be it Hebrew, Yiddish or Ladino.
>   **If you are naming your son after a woman, the Jewish name needs to be transposed to a male name/equivalent (and similarly if you're
>   naming your daughter after a man.)**

Quoted from: http://www.emohel.com/naming.php

It appears therefore that while a boy and be named after a woman the name must be changed, not left as a girl's name and visa versa.

Comment: That Web page doesn't cite any source, though, AFAICT.

Comment: why the downvote?