# Is there value in gender-adapted names?

Tags: names, women, men-male

There are various Hebrew names in use that are feminizations of pre-existing masculine names. (The opposite case may exist as well, but I can't think of any examples.)

Examples:

- Yaakova
- Rafaella
- Aharona

Do these names have the same intrinsic value (whatever that is) as the original forms of the names? Are there any sources that endorse or discourage this practice?

Comment: I once met a Yosefa, Davida and Avrahamit.

Comment: My mother once taught a Shmuela. ♫ "Shmuela de-Ville .. Shmuela de-Ville ...♫"

Comment: I know a _Yaakova_, a _Davida_, and a few people named _M'ira_ (although that **might** be taking the feminine verb rather than feminizing the men's name). I've never heard of _Titzchak_, _Taakov_, _Mosha_, or _Emraham_.

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: What about names in the other direction like Chuld or Devor?

Comment: I'm still wondering what "intrinsic value" means. If it's just that these new names are not found in Tanach, then we can ask the same question on a whole genre of Yiddish names such as Hirsh, Wolf, Sheyna, Mushka, and so forth. (And, no, I've never met anyone named So Forth.) [Someone had to say it...]

Comment: I've heard of Yisraela...

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12906/1059

Comment: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25b11.htm#20

Comment: @DoubleAA Note that Yaakova is itself a Biblical name. See Divrei HaYamim 1:4:36

Comment: Hadassah is perhaps a biblical example of this phenomenon.

Answer (score 13):

Per [Rabbi Shmuel Eliyahu](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/shiur.asp?id=8178) it is not proper to give names such as Rephaela, Daniela, etc.

> כמו כן ראוי לא לקרוא לבת בשם הדומה בשורשו לשם של בן, כמו: רפאלה,
>   דניאלה, שרונה, יוספה וכדומה. שזה עלול להפריע לילדה כשתגדל להיזכר תמיד
>   על שם פלוני שעל שמו היא קרויה.‏

Comment: +1. I wonder whether "להיזכר" was meant as a pun.

Comment: So no Daniella, but what about Danielle? That is more commonplace, isn't it?

Comment: @AdamMosheh ( *sorry for the late response!* ) Do you see a reason why the above logic shouldn't also apply to Danielle?

Comment: Yes. You don't?

Comment: שזה עלול להפריע לילדה כשתגדל להיזכר תמיד על שם פלוני שעל שמו היא קרויה.----- What does this mean?

Answer (score 5):

We see in the Torah that לאה named her daughter **דינה** - yet דינה's half brother was called **דן**!

So there seems to be no general issue with it.

That said - **if** there is *some spiritual value* in *naming after a person*, then that value is probably lost when morphing the name into something similar-sounding.

But if the reason for the name is to simply remember somebody - then why not?

Answer (score 0):

A growing multitude of Jewish people seem to be advancing this phenomenon, so it can't be a bad thing. After all - *Minhag Yisrael Torah Hee*!

Comment: Isn't it ''Hu''?

Comment: @DoubleAA, that's why this is such a confusing topic!