# Can a man and woman with the same name marry each other?

Tags: names, marriage

Suppose you have a man named Simcha. May he marry a woman named Simcha? (sources)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, but it's hard to imagine why the kiddushin wouldn't be chal.

Comment: Why would you not recommend it?

Comment: It would be weird.

Comment: The tzavvah only mentions mothers name if I remember.

Comment: @sam who says they have to go to the army? (only joking)

Comment: ma'aseh de'haveh kach haveh - http://www.shmais.com/component/jumi/results?key=&date=5%2F13%2F2004&num=14

Comment: Can you elaborate in your question and explain why you think this would be an issue?

Comment: @Menachem I can't see anything nogeya on shmais. To what are you linking?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: The second story "MAZEL TOV SIMI!". If I remember correctly, her name was also Simcha.

Comment: @DoubleAA I disagree with you because if there is a good Zivug, I don't think you should ruin it because of a name.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12906

Comment: @HachamGabriel Do you mean that you think they will work or that they already know each other and 'are in love'? If the latter, for sure don't break it off. If the former, then I encourage you to reassess if they actually will work well together having the same name.

Comment: @DoubleAA I was talking about if they are in love.

Comment: @HachamGabriel And I had originally been talking about setting them up milechatchila. So Kulei Alma Lo Pligi and Shalom al Yisrael!

Comment: I would so love to [see the invitation](http://imgur.com/dnIe2DG).

Comment: A friend often mentions that he knows a couple Eli & Elie.  I assume at least the girl's name is short for something longer, and perhaps both are shortenings of (presumably different) theophoric names.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In "What's in a Name", the English translation of Zusha Wilhelm's sefer "Ziv HaShemot", the [following is stated](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/273287/jewish/6-Names-Common-to-Both-Males-and-Females.htm):

> Some are particular not to marry a woman whose name is the same as one’s own. *(See Maasei Ish, Choshen Mishpat 7; See also Sdei Chemed, entry on Chasan VeKallah paragraph 7; See also Otzar HaPoskim, Even HaEzer end of ch. 2, and the Testament of R. Yehudah HaChassid 21)*

`I got a hold of the printed book and added the sources to this answer. The book itself not only brings the sources, but quotes most of them.`

Comment: Ziv Hashemot was recently posted online at hebrewbooks.org - http://www.hebrewbooks.org/53094 -- If I have a chance I'll find the page inside and link to it. If anyone wants to beat me to it, you're more than welcome

Answer (score 1):

I saw in the name of Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky that one of them should add a different name.

Comment: where did you see this?

Answer (score 0):

[According to Gitin 34b](http://dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=gitin&daf=34b&go=Go), if someone is known by two names and wants to divorce his wife, we write, "so-and-so and any name he has," and the same for someone who wants to divorce his wife who is known by two names. Elsewhere (though exactly where escapes me) it also says that when there are two people in the same city with the same name we add on "son of so-and-so" and go back as far as we have to and/or give as many other characteristics as we have to, in order to properly identify the person in question.

It would seem to me that we would do the same here - expand on their names and/or list characteristics to distinguish them from each other. Although, in this case, merely adding, "son of so-and-so" and "daughter of so-and-so" should suffice for identifying the man from the woman.

Comment: but what problem would arise that would require you to start adding on names in order to solve it? In both the case of marriage and divorce it is the husband giving to the wife, so there is no possibility of confusion. Also, even though they have the same name, one is Ben, and one is Bas.

Comment: @Menachem, on your last point, I addressed that at the end of my answer. I think you're right - I'm not sure there is a problem to begin with. I'm just pointing out measures which can be taken if there is some confusion, like if they were orphans and their parents were unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I know two Elis who married each other.

Comment: Did they do so under any rabbinic guidance?

Comment: Yes. It was an Orthodox wedding. To clarify, my wife knows. I only know of them.

Comment: I know the same. However, both of those are nicknames, not given names.