# Conversion and Hebrew Names

Tags: names, conversion-to-judaism

If a person is converting and considering their Hebrew name for being called to Torah, does the name have to be ancient Hebrew, or would a slightly different ethnic version of the same name be acceptable? Examples I can think of would be Elezar instead of Eleazar (three syllables instead of four), or Tevye instead of Tovia. Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26455

Comment: I saw that post, msh210, but thought it was not exactly the same question, since it was referring to "Modern names" ( which I assume would be "Joe" or "Mike"), as opposed to slight variations of the same name. The last comment on that page got close, and seemed to affirm the use of Yiddish variations, but I think the question bears repeating and clarifying.

Comment: (re your comment "thought it was not exactly the same question"): I agree. Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I hope you get your answer and stick around and enjoy the site. Don't forget -- this site is only for reference; for practical questions, consult your rabbi.

Comment: I am wondering with this practice, because In Gemara we says Antignos, Onkelos, Abaye, Qruspeday, Thodros, why our generation is differen? I know that Rabbanim gives hebrew names and I am not Chas Veshalom opposed to their advice, but I do not understand why this changed with time.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya _________. הצלחה רבה filling in the space.

Comment: mevaqesh, the  blank if filled. Its Eleazar. Beit Din was yesterday. Rabbi picked it from the choices, so that's good enough for me.

Comment: Congratulations Eleazar! If you want a user to see your comments, put @ before their username, like @benavraham